# scrapy memory consumption is increasing only

Tags: scrapy, python-3.6, twisted

I am using `scrapy` along with `scrapyrt` to create APIs. My application have around 20 spiders. We are using NFS server for load balancing on production. Unfortunately application using 40% and more space.

```
"stats": {
    "downloader/request_bytes": 12033,
    "downloader/request_count": 5,
    "downloader/request_method_count/GET": 4,
    "downloader/request_method_count/POST": 1,
    "downloader/response_bytes": 20165,
    "downloader/response_count": 5,
    "downloader/response_status_count/200": 3,
    "downloader/response_status_count/302": 1,
    "downloader/response_status_count/404": 1,
    "finish_reason": "finished",
    "finish_time": "2019-05-23 06:05:04",
    "item_scraped_count": 1,
    "log_count/DEBUG": 35,
    "log_count/INFO": 20,
    "memusage/max": 3399057408,
    "memusage/startup": 3399057408,
    "request_depth_max": 2,
    "response_received_count": 4,
    "scheduler/dequeued": 4,
    "scheduler/dequeued/memory": 4,
    "scheduler/enqueued": 4,
    "scheduler/enqueued/memory": 4,
    "start_time": "2019-05-23 06:05:01"
  }
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
14500 root      20   0 4999116 3.190g   7184 S   0.3 40.9 103:34.01 scrapyrt
```

I followed scrapy memory leak documentation so remove meta attribute from request, but still memory is increasing.

```py
class GarudaRetrieveBookingSpider(Spider):
    """get the pax, flight and fare details"""

    name = "garuda_retrieve_booking"
    meta = dict()
    formdata = dict()
    start_url = ''
    booking_code = ''
    output_dict = {'schedule_detail': [], 'pax_details': [], 'reservation_name': '', 'fare_details': {}}
    pax_count = 0
    adult_count = 0
    child_count = 0
    infant_count = 0
    ticket_list_adt_child = []
    ticket_list_inf = []
    # this variable is created to save rt command response data to pass in next call if there are no tickets
    rt_response = ''

    def start_requests(self):
        """
        :return: Request object
        """
        post_data = self.data
        garuda_session_id = post_data['parameter']['jSessionId']
        post_data["command"] = "IG"
        file_path = os.path.join(GARUDA_SESSION_FILES_PATH, TODAY_DATE, garuda_session_id + "_session.txt")
        session_data = get_cookies(self, file_path)
        self.start_url = GARUDA_KEEP_ALIVE_URL.format(session_id=session_data["jSessionId"], site=SITE, lang=LANGUAGE)
        self.meta = {"session_data": session_data, "post_data": post_data}
        return [Request(self.start_url, self.parse, errback=self.errback_httpbin)]

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        :param response:
        :return: FormRequest
        description: submit IG command
        """
        self.log("\n\nparse response: {}\n\n".format(response.text))
        if response.status != 200:
            error_message = 'parse method failed.'
            return {"status": False, "error_message": error_message}
        session_data = self.meta["session_data"]
        command = self.meta["post_data"]["command"]
        # override the command with current command
        session_data["tasks"][0]["command"]["command"] = command
        self.formdata = {
            "data": json.dumps(session_data)
        }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(CRYTO_COMMAND_URL, formdata=self.formdata,
                                 callback=self.ig_command_response, errback=self.errback_httpbin)
```

Comment: Have you tried the `JOB_DIR` setting to keep pending requests in disk instead of memory?

Comment: @Gallaecio I couldn't see any reference in scrapy settings. Can you please give an example.

Comment: I made a typo. It’s `JOBDIR`. In the [topic about debugging memory leaks](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html#too-many-requests) there’s a link to the [corresponding article](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html).

Comment: might it be that the problem is more related to scrapyrt than to the spider itself. As far as I see you scrape only 5 pages with a low payload (request_bytes, response_bytes).

Comment: @Raphael Is there any suggestions to write API without using scrapyrt?. Basically application scrap data from two travel domain sites and perform several activity like flight search, flight book issue ticket and get price etc.

Comment: @shashank Well, basically you can always write your own api. But that might be much extra work. First I would isolate the problem by using a dummy spider which does nothing but yielding a static item. If that works the problem might be related to your spider. Im not familiar enough with scrapyrt to tell how one could narrow down the problem on the scrapyrt side. If you really need to write the api yourself you can use scrapys CrawlerRunner to run a spider from a python module and connect to the signal spider_closed to access your items.

Comment: @Gallaecio I have around 20 spider, how will I give JOBDIR path for all of them. following is in scrapy documentation. But I am confuse how to use.
It’s important to note that this directory must not be shared by different spiders, or even different jobs/runs of the same spider

Comment: You can pass `-s` to `scrapy crawl` to define a setting.

Comment: Have you found the solution yet? I am having the exact same issue even with `jobdir`.

Comment: No, I haven't got any effective solution.